# attaching a log file as an Email attachment - log content become unreadable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm sending an execution log through an Email in my code, but the decoding is failing the file content becomes:

```
mg×£h¿m5ë]÷çMC<ä“†ÛiÿývïM5ç]ô÷û²È¨Ÿÿ{mí×‡6áþû÷W5åíÞ{¦šãnºç¯î®[«–m§ÿé‹›²Ö {V³º·°y»"µë'zßìzË"¢r÷¶ÞÑÝxsnï¿us^
```

I'm running the next code:

```
 def send_email(self):
        email_filename = WebUIOrgResorces.logfilename
        fp = codecs.open(email_filename, 'rb')
        filecontent = fp.read()
        encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact stacktrace of your error?

Comment: @jean-Francois
I didn't got the error now but I'm getting the attachment text :


¢ý´×­µÓ;@TX§ŠÈ^uª¹ë-®s(Ÿ^¢ý´×­µÓ;@Ta†ÛiÿývïM5ãÝzçû²È¨Ÿ÷Üi¶Ýß½÷ëÝyÛÆÚ{ÍºßO{íÏsOÞ•éžžßôç4Û½|óúÓ½v÷û^ÆÛ²È¨œ‡_q¦Ûw~÷ß¯uçoiï6ë}=ï·<mÍ"wNxÓM»×Ï8ß­;×okœÊ'×ƒh¿m5ëmtçNÃ)â²Eê®zËkœÊ'×ƒh¿m5ëmtçNÄE‘Eë(º·½©nz+%zË-…©ô½©nz+=çšç2‰õàÚ/ÛMzÛ]9Ó°ÄA†8m¶Ÿÿ×nôÓ^=×®±ë,Š‰ÿ}Æ›mÝûß~½×¼m§¼Û­ô÷¾Üñ·4þÇ+yéì†‹lzË"¢r}Æ›mÝûß~½×¼m§¼Û­ô÷¾Üñ·4®s(Ÿ^
¢ý´×­µÓ;@TX§ŠÈ^uª¹ë-®s(Ÿ^
¢ý´×­µÓ;@T11!¶Úÿ]»ÓMx÷^¹þÇ¬²*'ý÷m·wï}ú÷^vñ¶žón·ÓÞûsÆÜÒÇ¬²*'!×Üi¶Ýß½÷ëÝyÛÆÚ{ÍºßO{íÏsJç2‰õàÚ/ÛMzÛ]9Ó°ÄA…Šx¬…çQz«ž²Úç

Comment: that is not base64. Can you [edit] your question to update it?